# Visual Studio 2012 unable to attach to Silverlight app(preferably running in Firefox)

Tags: c#, silverlight, firefox, visual-studio-2012

Since my upgrade to Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012, I am unabled to attach to the plugin-cotainer.exe process of Firefox in order to debug my Silverlight 5 app.

Previously in VS2010 this worked without a hassle.
But whatever I do, my symbols aren't loaded.

I have tried to change the dom.ipc.plugins.enabled in the about:config.
I have delete all temporary files, bin and obj folders of my project and multiple times cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Even Interenet Explorer does not allow me to attach code to a Silverlight app.

Basically I don't see and Silverlight type process in the Attach to Process dialog.

Does anyone have anymore suggestions what I can check?

Comment: Make sure you have the developer Silverlight client installed.

Comment: I have the following installed: Microsoft Silverlight, Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK, Microsoft Silverlight 5 SDK and Microsoft Silverlight 5 Toolkit December 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue based on this forum post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/960abca1-5f10-4608-ad72-93ecef6e70a7/windows-81-killed-my-silverlight-development-environment?forum=silverlightdevtools

Seems the upgrade of Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 was the culprit. I only a new dev workstation since a month and short after I upgraded to 8.1... when it was still 8, I think I remember being able to do some Silverlight debugging.
Uninstalling and Reinstalling all Silverlight programs fixed the issue.
Visual Studio prompted me with reinstalling the Silverlight Developers Tools.  This propably did the final trick.